# Why is list concatenation in SML right associative?

Tags: list, sml, ml

In Ullman's SML book

> Most
>   unusual is that the :: (list cons) and @ (list concatenation) operators are right-associative, meaning that they group
>   from the right instead of the left as do most operators we have seen.

I understand the reason why cons is right associative: the second operand must be a list, and the return is a list.

Why is list concatenation in SML right associative, given that "most operators we have seen" in SML are left associative?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The cost of concatenation is linear in the length of the left operand, because that has to be copied. Consequently, `x @ (y @ z)` is cheaper than `(x @ y) @ z`, because the latter would copy the list `x` twice.

Also, you'll sometimes want to mix cons and concat operators (`x @ y :: z`), which would be more clumsy if they had different precedence or associativity.